# Find employees who haven’t worked between certain times based on ‘clock ins’ and ‘clock outs’

Tags: mysql, database, sql-date-functions

I have a “clock in” table for employees with attributes start time and end time.
Each employee clocks in and clocks out when they start and finish work and the table is similar to this:

```
Employee_no Start time            End time
16          2019-04-01 08:00:20   2019-04-02 12:00:10
13          2019-04-01 10:00:20   2019-04-01 14:00:20
31          2019-04-01 14:00:20   2019-04-01 17:00:20
```

How to find the employees who haven’t worked between 13 and 16 o’clock based on the start and end time?

Comment: This data set seems unlikely to be fairly representative of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause to exhibit employees that never worked between 13h and 16h:

```
select employee_no
from mytable
group by employee_no
having max(hour(start_time) <= 16 and hour(end_time) >= 13) = 0
```

If you want the full list of records in the table that do not overlap the 13h-16h timeslot, then:

```
select *
from mytable
where not (hour(start_time) <= 16 and hour(end_time) >= 13)
```

Comment: @Ella: any particular reason why you unaccepted the answer?